# How to update schema?

Tags: ydn-db

Is there any way to update schema?  I've created a db with schema now I want to add an index to it.  How to add an extra index to existing store?

Thanks,
-Kesav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your schema. If you define schema version, remember to increase it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If you use SQL Server, on management studio you change your table e save the new Schema. Then you run this script.